# search user uid in uniquemember - ldap

Tags: ldap

I have some user within a uid within uniquemember.
How to create a show that only the ldapsearch uid?
If today I run the command below, the Results is the entire contents of uniquemember and I just want to return the uid:

ldapsearch -x -h serverldap.com -p 389 -D uid=pdi00usr,ou=bind,ou=users,ou=access,o=com,c=br -W -b o=com,c=br -s sub "(&(uniqueMember=*F*)(cn=pdi*))"

```
# pdiasc01, pdi, aplic, groups, access, com, br
dn: cn=pdiasc01,ou=pdi,ou=aplic,ou=groups,ou=access,o=com,c=br
description: Administrator
objectclass: bb
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectclass: top
cn: pdiasc01
uniquemember: uid=dummy
uniquemember: uid=f6802561,ou=func,ou=users,ou=access,o=com,c=br
uniquemember: uid=f3799300,ou=func,ou=users,ou=access,o=com,c=br

# pdiapf02, pdi, aplicacao, grupos, acesso, bb, br
dn: cn=pdiapf02,ou=pdi,ou=aplic,ou=groups,ou=access,o=com,c=br
description: Aprover
objectclass: bb
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectclass: top
cn: pdiapf02
uniquemember: uid=dummy
uniquemember: uid=f3799300,ou=func,ou=users,ou=access,o=com,c=br
uniquemember: uid=f6802561,ou=func,ou=users,ou=access,o=bb,c=br
```

i need a resulta like this:

uid=f3799300
uid=f6802561

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options as far as I can see.

- First would be to simply pipe your output through `grep` and do some `sed` (or `awk`) magic to remove everything after the first comma or
- Second use the returned `uid` for a second query for the entry with the `dn` returned by `uid` and query for the `uid` of that object (which should be what you are looking for)